# special boolean operator

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, code-request, boolean-computation

I am familiar with some boolean operators. I want to access an operator that does a procedure same as below one. But for simplicity, we can say in the first step we ignore `i` and `j`th part of lists in order to use above operators. But for `i` and `j`th part we just add them to each other. I mean

IF except `i` and `j` according elements of two lists are different, the output has to be zero. For example in `{0,1,0,0,1},{1,1,0,0,1}` the first element of the first list is `0` but the first element of the second list is `1`. The result has to be zero. but if there is not a such situation, I mean even if `i` and `j` be different but other elements are accordingly (one by one) equal, the result has to be in a such way that `i` and `j`th parts added accordingly but instead of other element must be put zero.

```
Assume: i=2;j=5;
Oerator[{0,1,0,0,1},{0,1,0,0,1}]={0,2,0,0,2};
Oerator[{1,1,0,0,1},{1,1,0,0,1}]={0,2,0,0,2};
Oerator[{0,1,0,0,1},{1,1,0,0,1}]=0;
Oerator[{0,1,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,1}]={0,1,0,0,2};
Oerator[{0,1,0,0,1},{0,1,0,0,0}]={0,2,0,0,1};
Oerator[{0,1,0,1,1},{0,0,0,0,1}]=0;
Oerator[{0,1,0,1,1},{0,0,0,1,1}]={0,1,0,0,2};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can be added"?

Comment: must be added. not can be. so sorry

Comment: Why are the third and sixth outputs `0`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: If I had to guess: The output is 0 if the elements at indexes other than `i`/`j` differ, otherwise it's the sum of the two arguments, with 0 everywhere except postions `i` and `j`

Comment: One possible implementation that reproduces your outputs is: `Operator[i__][l__] := 
 If[With[{d = {l}\[Transpose]}, 
   And @@ Equal @@@ d[[Complement[Range@Length@d, {i}]]]], 
  Normal[Total@{l} SparseArray@Thread[{i} -> 1]], 0]` (used as `Operator[i,j][...]`) - but without a clearer explanation we can't be sure what exactly it is you want

Comment: please see, I edited the post. If I explain perhaps I could not say in a suitable English sentences. For this reason I brought some examples.

Comment: If the output contains `2`, it's not a Boolean operator. I'm afraid I can't understand what is being asked.

Comment: @Jens, I think we can ignore them and after Boolean operation, on the other elements, we just added ignored terms. is not it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you have clarified what you want, I'll post my (slightly modified) attempt from the comments as an answer:

```
Operator[i__][o__] :=
 If[
  Equal @@ {o}[[All, Complement[Range@Length@First@{o}, {i}]]],
  Normal[
   Total@{o} SparseArray@Thread[{i} -> 1]
  ],
  0
 ]
```

It is used as

```
Operator[2,5][{0,1,0,0,1},{0,1,0,0,1}]
Operator[2,5,6][{0,1,0,1,0,1},{0,1,0,0,1,1}]
MyOp = Operator[2,5]
MyOp[{0,1,0,0,1},{0,1,0,0,1}]
```

(works with an arbitrary amount of operands and indexes)

How it works:

- `Complement[Range@Length@First@{l}, {i}]` gets all indexes except the specified ones
- These indexes are then extracted from `All` operands `{o}`
- If the resulting lists are `Equal`:

  - Take the `Total` of all operands (element wise)
  - Multiply the result (element wise), with array where only indexes `{i}` are `1`, the rest is `0`
- Otherwise, return `0`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Unfortunately I was traveling and I could not check your answer sooner.